# Can we customize rev column data type in Hibernate envers revinfo table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

Default DDL of `revinfo` table is like shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE revinfo (
    rev int4 NOT NULL,
    revtstmp int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT revinfo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (rev)
);
```

My requirement is to have `rev` column as `non-monotonic` preferably of `UUID` type. But my exploration suggest that `@RevisionNumber` annotation mandates rev field to accept `int, Integer, Long & long` data types only.

Does Hibernate envers support changing data type for rev column, if so than how it can be done, or are there some alternatives available to implement audit mechanism for table without the need of revinfo table?

Comment: Its not possible to change the type of `Revision Number` to string only allowed values are int, long, one possible solution that I can think of is using one more column in REVINFO table using Custom Revision entity and Storing UUID in that column.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that @RevisionNumber by Hibernate Envers only supports integer-based data types (int, Integer, Long, and long). However, you can still use a UUID data type for your revision identifier column, but you would need to implement your own custom revision entity listener to generate and assign UUID values to the column.

Here is the link to the documentatio that might help you with that:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers

Comment: Even on creating the Custom Revision entity, the Revision Id in revision entity needs to be int, long, using String UUID it gives the same error.

Comment: yeah, this is really pity ... there is probably no way how to replace int/long by uuid 